# How do I get my Juju Charm officially recognized?

Tags: juju

I've just completed and tested a charm I made for Juju. I've followed the directions on [the Juju Charms page](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/authors-charm-store#submitting-a-new-charm) and pushed the charm to the store.

How do I get it into the charms tool or the "Charms Store"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've pushed, published, and set the right permissions to the charm store your charm is immediately available for people to deploy.

Some charms live at the root space of the charm store, for example: http://jujucharms.com/ntp

We call these charms `recommended` and they are peer reviewed and production-quality. These have more rigorous requirements than personally namespaced charms, you can follow those instructions here:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/authors-charm-policy